# Significance of imaginary value of spin angular momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, quantum-spin

If I put $$-1/2$$ in the formula $$\hbar*\sqrt{s(s+1)}$$ I get $$\hbar*1/2*i.$$ Is it allowed? If yes, what does it indicate?

Comment: You should understand the SU(2) group and its Casimir to understand why you cannot do that. More generally, if you see a formula you may want to look at its derivation before putting random values for the variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spin is always a positive quantity. What you have as $-1/2$ is the $s_z$ value i.e. the component of the spin along the $z$ axis. Likewise the formula you have is for the for the angular momentum $L$ not $L_z$, so the formula takes $s$ as an argument not $s_z$.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, it should be $\hbar * \sqrt{s(s+1)}$.
According to the conventional definition of the spin quantum number, $s$ needs to be positive. Your secondary quantum number $m_s$ will then run from $-s$ to $s$ in steps of $1$.
So for a spin 1/2 particle like an electron, you obtain possible values of $-\hbar/2$ and $\hbar/2$.
Check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_quantum_number) or - even better - any basic quantum mechanics book for a simple overview.